# Error in python loop while trying scraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi i'm new to web scraping and i'm trying to follow a tutorial but i have issues accessing certain items! This is the page i want to scrape https://www.newegg.com/todays-deals?cm_sp=Homepage_4spots-_--_-12182020 , and I want to get the title, brand and the price of the product, everything works fine outside of the loop! but i have errors while creating the loop for all the products

```
#this is  the loop to scrape all items from the webpage
containers = pagesoup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
for con in containers:
  title = con.img["title"]
  titleco=con.findAll("div",{"class":"item-branding"})
  brand= titleco[0].img["title"]
  priceco=con.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
  priceco[0].text.strip()
```

i get this error

----> 5 brand= titleco[0].img["title"] 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try just printing `titleco`. I think you'll find it's null. So the issue is coming from the line above it, specifically, that the `.finall(...)` call isn't returning anything.

Comment: No, outside of this loop I got everything that i need to scrape!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every `item-branding` item on your page has an `img` : so in some cases, `titleco[0].img` is `None`, hence why you get an error when trying to access the `"title"` element.

You run into another issue later with your `price-current`, too: sometimes you find zero matches, hence you get an error when trying to access the first element of the `ResultSet` via `priceco[0]`. Or at least I do, but your site seems to be partially unavailable to my country, so you may not get the same results.

Here's a version of your code that runs:

```
containers = pagesoup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})
for con in containers:
    title = con.img["title"]
    titleco = con.findAll("div", {"class": "item-branding"})
    if titleco[0].img != None:
        brand = titleco[0].img["title"]
    priceco = con.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})
    if len(priceco) > 0:
        priceco[0].text.strip()
```